# Android system app

Tags: android, system

I'm developing a remote-control application for Android.
I want to be able to lock/unlock the screen.

To do this there are two ways:

- Making the app a Device Administrator.
- Using [`PowerManager.goToSleep()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep(long)), which requires the [DEVICE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER) permission, **which is a system permission**.

So eclipse tells me "this permission is only granted to system apps".
I really need this and some other system permissions in my app, as it's a remote control app that must be able to control system features.

From the [support page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469):

> Uploading System Applications
>   Most developers will not need to upload system applications and may ignore this section. System applications may come pre-installed on certain devices and may or may not already be published in the Play store.
>   If you need to upload a system application and encounter an error message when doing so, please contact us. Please be sure to select the Publishing issues and distribution option.

If I'm understanding it right, It's possible to make a system application. **how?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm developing a remote-control application for Android

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps if you run as root, or you download the Android source code, modify it, and roll it into your own ROM mod.

> If I'm understanding it right, It's possible to make a system application. how?

Build your own ROM mod. Sign the app with the same signing key as is used to sign your ROM mod. Put your app in your ROM mod. Install your ROM mod on your device.

This, of course, will limit your app's distribution to those devices running your ROM mod.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of “system” permissions are really `SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM` permissions. For those, you need to do one of the following:

1. After building the APK, install it as a system app.
2. Sign the app with the same key as the Android distribution on your device.

For the first option, you would need to be root on your device. Regular APKs reside in `/data/app`, while system APKs need to be placed in  a different folder (on Android 6 and 7 it’s `/system/priv-app`, earlier versions may differ). However, this is not very suitable for an app to be distributed to end users, especially if your target audience is not very tech-savvy.

For the second option, you need to build Android from source for your target device. If you sign the app with the same key as your Android build, then users running that build of Android can install it in the usual manner.